# modular routing in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, reactive-programming

I am building a simple website in which I have a route to category pages. I want to use a single dynamic route to move between pages.I am using vue-router for this project and the routes need to load different component

These are the desired routes for the website
example: '/shop/men' , '/shop/women','/shop/kids'

This my index.js file for router in which gender is appended in the last deciding which component to load the issue I am facing is how to handle this and load different component on depending on it
    router-> index.js:

```
{
        name: 'shop',
        path: '/shop/:gender',
        component: menCategoryViewsHandler('mencategory')
}

views -> viewHandler -> mencategory.js:

'use strict'

import Handle from '../mencategory.vue'

const camelize = str => str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)

// This is a factory function for dynamically creating root-level views,
// since they share most of the logic except for the type of items to display.
// They are essentially higher order components wrapping the respective vue file.
export default function ViewsHandler (type) {
  console.log('1',type)
  return {
    name: `${type}-mencategory-view`,
    asyncData ({store, route}) {
      //@todo : add the ssr and routerbefore load change script here
      return Promise.resolve({})
    },
    title: camelize(type),
    render (h) {
      return h(Handle,
        {
          props: {type},
        },
      )
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) along with a wrapper component which renders the correct Category component. This would handled by [passing props to components](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html).

```
// CategoryResolver.vue
import menCategory from './mencategory'
import womenCategory from './womencategory'
import kidsCategory from './kidscategory'

const components = {
  menCategory,
  womenCategory,
  kidsCategory
}
export default {
  functional: true,
  props: ['category'],
  render(h, ctx) {
    return h(`components[${category}Category`], ctx.data, ctx.children)
  }
}
```

Then your router would be defined as such:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/shop/:category', component: CategoryResolver, props: true  }
  ]
})
```

Say `menCategoryViewsHandler('mencategory')` returns a component called MenCat. It must have a prop that matches the route above, in this example `category`. In MenCat you would define:

```
export default {
    props: ['category'],
    ...
 }
```

Vue router will pass the matching url prop into your component for you.

Comment: Can we do it in a .js file instead of vue as all my handler are in .js

Comment: {
        name: 'shop',
        path: '/shop/:gender',
        component: menCategoryViewsHandler('mencategory')
}

Comment: That's fine, the important part is having the gender prop in the mencategory component.

Comment: I am little confused here can you edit on the above code

Comment: I've added some more info to the answer